# Maps between surface groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $S_g$ denote the fundamental group of a genus $g$ closed orientable surface.  Are all maps $S_g \to S_h$ where $g<h$ necessarily trivial?

Comment: No! You can always collapse $S_g \to T^2 \to S^1$ and then map into a non-null-homotopic loop in $S_h$. But you necessarily have kernel (and not only that, you have kernel in homology).

Comment: Ah OK yes thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, see my comment for a nontrivial construction. But in a more positive direction, every map $S_g \to S_h$, $g < h$, factors (up to homotopy) through the $1$-skeleton of $S_h$.

1) Consider the image of $\pi_1(S_g)$ in $\pi_1(S_h)$. This subgroup corresponds to the fundamental group of some covering space of $\pi_1(S_h)$. Since finite degree covering spaces of $S_h$ have higher genus than $S_h$, so it suffices to see that no quotient of $\pi_1(S_g)$ can be a surface group of higher genus. To see this, note that $\pi_1(S_g)$ is $2g$-generated, and cannot be generated by fewer elements (look at the abelianization), and taking quotients only decreases the minimal number of generators necessary. Thus the image of $\pi_1(S_g)$ cannot have finite index in $\pi_1(S_h)$. So the map $S_g \to S_h$ factors through some noncompact covering space $S$ of $S_h$.

Pick the cell structure of $S$ so that the map $S \to S_h$ is cellular. Now (nontrivial fact): any noncompact surface deformation retracts to a 1-dimensional subcomplex. Call that $C \subset S$. Thus the map $S_g \to S_h$ factors through $C$, and thus has image inside the 1-skeleton of $S_h$, as desired.

Comment: Wonderful!  I have one question - in showing that the subgroup can not have finite index, we are using that a quotient of $S_g$ that is a surface group is necessarily of genus less than $g$.  Why is this the case?

Comment: @user101010 Euler characteristic considerations, since covering spaces are multiplicative under Euler characteristic, and $\chi(S_g) = 2-2g$. If that's negative, taking a covering space makes it more negative, and thus increases genus. When the Euler characteristic is zero we're working with tori and your question is about maps $S^2 \to T^2$ which isn't super exciting, and when it's $2$ it's the sphere and your question is void.

Comment: Yes - I understand that shows that if we have a covering of one surface by another, then the genus must lower.  But in arriving at a contradiction we are saying that some quotient of $S_g$ must be a surface subgroup of $S_h$ (thus must have genus greater than $h$) and...(How do we conclude?)

Comment: @user101010 Does my update answer your question?

Comment: I see yes, thanks!